# Sliding panel jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a sliding panel at the top of my website design, but its default is to be open at the m,oment on page load - how can I get it to be closed on default and then click the toggle to open, instead of the reverse which it is doing now? JQuery below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#toggle").click(function(){

        $(".panel").toggle("slow");

        $(this).toggleClass("active");

        return false;

    });

});
```

Comment: Just before the click event, set it to be closed via $('.panel').hide()

Answer (score 3):

Use the class panel and make display property as none which could it wont display at the moment of loading the page.

.panel{display:none; }

Answer (score 3):

Use this class and make display property as none which could it wont display on window loading.

.panel{display:none; }

Comment: lhlkjhjlhkjlhkjlkjldfsdsfdasfdfsbdcvcxbvcnbjhkl.j.ljkl.jk.,.

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to prevent on document load to see that panel "flash" from 'visible' to hidden than just hide it initially with CSS:

```
.panel{display:none;}
```